# Biased estimators

Tags: statistics

For bias or unbiased estimator, in a proof I found for MSE's, the following expression was equated to 0 and I don't understand why:

$$E[(\hat \theta - E[\hat \theta])] = 0$$

$\hat \theta$ is not unbiased

Comment: By linearity of the expectated value, we always have $\mathbb {E}(\hat\theta - \mathbb {E} (\hat\theta)) =0$. The bias is defined by $\mathbb {E}(\hat\theta - \theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget how $E[\hat \theta]$ is just a fixed scalar. You could set $E[\hat \theta] = c$ (a constant). Then as Harry49 noted:
$$E[\hat \theta -c] = E[\hat \theta] - c = E[\hat \theta]-E[\hat \theta] = 0$$